# Firebase database structure conflict

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

So I decided to think about how to proceed with the structure in my app before moving forward with the coding, since I'm kinda new to NoSQL.

```
 Users:
    ID
      email: "john@doe.com"
      name: "John Doe"
      profile_pic_path: "https://...".
      language: "en"
      exp_points: 1284

  Projects:
    /$PROJECT_ID
      title: "For whom the bell tolls"
      image: "etc.png"

  project_roles:
    /$PROJECT_ID
      $userId1: 5
      $userId2: 6

  roles:
    5: "Editor"
    6:" Writer"
```

So now I need to add `orders` to `projects`. Each `order` is a list of `items`.

**My question is:**

1. My structure is as flat as possible. Since I'm new to NoSQL, am I doing it right? If there's anything you would have changed, I would like to hear and learn as soon as I'm trying to build everything with maxed stability.

Comment: Where is `project_tasks` node?

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling, I mean `project_orders`

Comment: @rainman What does it matter?

Comment: A user can only be in one project right?

Comment: Do you want to show all projects? All users? All users in a project?

Comment: @ZuraSekhniashvili No. User can be in multiple project in different roles. that's why I have this huge structure. To your second comment: Yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I'm start to learn about json databases, in this case firebase realtime databse... And have questions about correct schema to firebase... When you want to create firebase database you need to have present 3 concepts:

- Avoid nesting data: Firebase gives support to 32 nesting nodes and it's necessary to use all nodes? No... Your database it's more simple and fast to read info with less nodes. Remember, when you call the parent node, the firebase return all secondary nodes information.
- Compacting the data structures to evade innecessary nesting nodes, this one helps you to have more fast firebase database.
- Creating scale data or bidireccional nodes this it's possible the most important... Because it's a possible that you need to see the orders of a project or the orders of a user, here you have a bidereccional node, then you need to create a index json object, to do more efficient database.

If you apply this concepts you can build a good JSON database. To read more about this see this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) with examples and google information. I can't do your schema because you know more than us what you need for your app, read about it, follow example and build the best schema. This [youtuber](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdssc-pDiZ7OD78kJVp4habTynj-Etwhm) talks about good practises for firebase realdatabase and their rules. Greetings!!